# showing variable value with exception message

Tags: php, debugging, magento, error-handling

I am trying to debug invoicing issue by checking each stage for variables / objects with very basic approach...

I have the following code

```
$capOrder = $payment->getOrder();
$capTransID = $capOrder->getPayment()->getLastTransId();

if(!empty($capTransID )){

Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('paygate')->__('zaffar_checking for trans  ID. its not EMPTY'));

}
```

My output for this looks like

> zaffar_checking for trans ID. its not EMPTY

I want to echo the value of `$capTransID` too with my custom error message...like

> zaffar_checking for trans ID. its not EMPTY--value is XXXX

how can I do it?? I am unable to find a way to combine / concatenate variable with error message..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this to

```
if(!empty($capTransID )){

Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('paygate')->__("zaffar_checking for trans  ID. its not EMPTY--value is $capTransID"));

}
```

Comment: dont say that :(, why didn't I tried that?? going for complexity always :(

Comment: hell on me, I was trying so many things, and believe me I did not even tried for once..

Comment: just a question, If I nee to echo the complete OBJECT like order , or payment, can I show that in the same way?

Comment: yw, it won't work for the object, you can `var_dump` the object or use something like `Mage::log(var_dump($order))` then check the log files.

Comment: yes, it does not show anything, I have tried it for more then once, on different objects / variables, any idea?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23422/discussion-between-n-e-w-b-e-e-and-alectmh)